# Create new cols by comparing values from old cols

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, compare, multiple-columns

Input dataframe:

| Item | L | W | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | 3 | 5 | 8 |
| I2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| I3 | 6 | 9 | 1 |
| I4 | 7 | 3 | 4 |

The output dataframe should be as below. Create 3 new columns: L_n, W_n, H_n by checking the values from L, W, H cols. L_n is the longest dimension, W_n is the medium and H_n is the shortest dimension.

| Item | L | W | H | L_n | W_n | H_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I1 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 8 | 5 | 3 |
| I2 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| I3 | 6 | 9 | 1 | 9 | 6 | 1 |
| I4 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 4 | 3 |

Comment: how exactly is this new column created?
May be you should more concrete logic/description about it, for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating an array ([`array`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array)), sorting it ([`array_sort`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort)) and selecting elements one-by-one ([`element_at`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.element_at.html#pyspark.sql.functions.element_at)).

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('I1', 3, 5, 8),
     ('I2', 2, 1, 2),
     ('I3', 6, 9, 1),
     ('I4', 7, 3, 4)],
    ['Item', 'L', 'W', 'H']
)
arr = F.array_sort(F.array('L', 'W', 'H'))
df = df.select(
    '*',
    F.element_at(arr, 3).alias('L_n'),
    F.element_at(arr, 2).alias('W_n'),
    F.element_at(arr, 1).alias('H_n'),
)
df.show()
# +----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
# |Item|  L|  W|  H|L_n|W_n|H_n|
# +----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
# |  I1|  3|  5|  8|  8|  5|  3|
# |  I2|  2|  1|  2|  2|  2|  1|
# |  I3|  6|  9|  1|  9|  6|  1|
# |  I4|  7|  3|  4|  7|  4|  3|
# +----+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: when i create arr will the granularity at item level be maintained ?

Comment: getting this error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'array_sort'